# Jenkins start a job if other job show a specific string on log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

So, I have job A and job B, I need that job A start job B only if a specific string appear on log of job A

Comment: I tried to use Run Condition Plugin but can't make it work

Comment: I found a plugin that did the trick, Text Finder Run Condition Plugin